Missing read access to /etc/chrony/chrony.keys and Cannot open /var/log/chrony/tracking.log due to permission denied
i hope this post finds you well, i have a three NTP servers ( two chrony , and one ntpsec ) , that peer to peer to each , the problem is when i pass to authentication ( symmetric key between ntp servers ), when i run sudo systemctl restart chronyd it always :
]: chronyd version 4.5 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP ]: Wrong owner of /run/chrony (UID = 110)
1: Disabled command socket /run/chrony/chronyd.sock
]: Loaded 2 symmetric keys
]
]: Missing read access to /etc/chrony/chrony.keys: Permission denied Initial frequency -4.700 ppm
]: Could not open /var/log/chrony/tracking.log Permission denied
]: Loaded seccomp filter (level 1)
Started chrony.service- chrony, an NTP client/server.
]: Could not open /var/log/chrony/measurements.log: Permission denied

whoever i do :
>  sudo useradd -r -s /usr/sbin/nologin -d /var/lib/chrony -U chrony
> sudo chown -R chrony:chrony /etc/chrony sudo chown -R chrony:chrony
> /var/log/chrony sudo chown -R chrony:chrony /var/lib/chrony sudo chown
> -R chrony:chrony /run/chrony sudo chmod -R 755 /var/log/chrony sudo chmod -R 750 /var/lib/chrony sudo chmod -R 750 /run/chrony sudo chmod
> 640 /etc/chrony/chrony.keys

